# TFS how can I group my files in pending changes window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

If I'm working on lots of things at a time I would like to group the files that I've changed into 'change lists' similar to [TortoiseSVN change list feature](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html). Is there a way to do this in TFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this in TFS?

Not in the way linked to (as far sa I can tell).

You can use "Shelvesets" to save ongoing changes (and, optionally, remove them as pending changes in your workspace) which allows saving your state when switching to work on something else.